# To what extent is it true that everyone is born upon fitrah?

Tags: allah, islamic-philosophy, belief, fitrah

I often recall my memory from the past when I was first recognised God. When I was a child and misbehaving and my mother said "Remember God is watching you" and reply "Who's he(God)"?. That memory casts me doubts regarding whether it's true that everyone is born with instinct to believe in God. I often think that is it possible that it's not true for everyone and often think that could it be the case that some believe in God not because it was in their instinct but that is what they were told since their childhood?

Answer (score 0):

No, we are not born with the knowledge of God.

God has sent the prophets to make us know about Him, and to find the right path to live and to prepare for Jannah.

All children of mine asked me the very same question, and the answer is not easy because, say, a 4 year old child needs an answer that is appropriate to his/her age, which has to be simplified. It's the obligation of the parents to lead smaller children to the belief; others may contribute later.

There is an instinct to be able to believe, but we do not believe in the One God Allah without education.